# BroadcastReceiver set up overlooked something

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to setup a BroadcastReceiver to handle scheduled events. I have been following http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks/ , and had the feature working, or so I believed. Would someone help me find why it is not working now?

Here is the receiver:

```
public class ScheduledEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "ScheduledEventReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "ScheduledEventReceiver " + intent.getData());
    Intent activity = new Intent(context, Model.class);
    activity.setData(intent.getData());
    context.startService(activity);
}
}
```

And a bit of the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.ScheduledEventReceiver" />
```

And from the DialogFragment which is sending the Intent:

```
private void setEventTest(Calendar time) {
    setEvent(getActivity(), Uri.parse("http://teststring"), time);
}

private void setEvent(Context context, Uri data, Calendar when) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScheduledEventReceiver.class);
    intent.setData(data);
    PendingIntent scheduledEvent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager schedule = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    schedule.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), scheduledEvent);
}
```

The reason I believe it is not working is that I never see Log output from onReceive.

Comment: Is your `ScheduledEventsReceiver` in a `receiver` subpackage of your application?

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. If you write it up I will give you the point.

Comment: You are welcome, and wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure your receiver is actually in a subpackage of your activity, if not, remove the '.receiver'.

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.ScheduledEventReceiver" />
```